# Confusion regarding lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, lambda

reference [Removing FrameworkElements on Animation Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778795/removing-frameworkelements-on-animation-completion)

In above question, how come we access 'myrect' in lambda expression but can't access in traditional method.

lambda expression :

```
SB.Completed += (s,e) => myCanvas.Children.Remove(myRect);
```

traditional approach :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lastFire = DateTime.Now;
        }

        DateTime lastFire;

        private void myCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan T = nowTime.Subtract(lastFire);

            if (T.TotalMilliseconds > 200)
            {
                lastFire = nowTime;
                Random Rand = new Random();

                Rectangle myRect = (Rectangle)FindResource("MyRect");
                myRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)Rand.Next(256), (byte)Rand.Next(256), (byte)Rand.Next(256)));
                Point myLoc = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);
                Canvas.SetLeft(myRect, myLoc.X - 10);
                Canvas.SetTop(myRect, myLoc.Y - 10);
                myCanvas.Children.Add(myRect);

                Storyboard SB = (Storyboard)FindResource("GrowSquare");
                SB.Completed += new EventHandler(SB_Completed);
                SB.Begin(myRect);
            }

        }

        void SB_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but can't access in traditional method." I could not find a single word saying anythign close to that. Please specify where you read it.

Comment: If you mean you can't access it in `SB_Completed`, that's because it's out of scope there. You can pass it to the event handler by creating your own custom `EventArgs` and create an `EvenHandler<CustomEventArgs>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you create a lambda expression the compiler will convert it to a class with the 'method' you created and fields for all the captured variables in the lambda expression.
See [this](https://youtu.be/gc1AxbNybvw?t=1606) talk from David Wengier if you are interested.

So lets take the following code:

```cs
public void Foo()
{
   string bar = "Bar";
   Action action = x => Console.WriteLine(bar);
   action();
}
```

It will convert it to something like the following:

```cs
private sealed class Helper {

  public string bar;

  public void action()
  {
     Console.WriteLine(bar);
  }
}
```

And in your "traditional" method your variable `myrect` would be out of scope. What are [scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)?

Comment: Thanks @twenty for explaination and video link. Nicely explained in video and loved to know about memory advantage of lambdas.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark it as an answer if it helped :)